# Playlist with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I have some audio files (a.mp3, b.mp3, c.mp3) and a random array (b, c, a). I want to play these audio files in the given order, like in a playlist.
This is my code so far:

```
<audio id="player" />

<script>
//... extract

var player = document.getElementById('player');
player.src="audio/"+array[0]+".mp3";
player.play(); // play first file

for(c = 0; c < array.length; c++){
var next = "audio/"+array[c]+".mp3";
document.write(next);
    player.addEventListener("ended",function() {
        this.src = next;
        this.play();
    });
}
</script>
```

The problem is, after playing the first file, the second file is being played forever. It never stops and the next file can't be played.

Comment: @Paulpro I guess the array only has two items.

Comment: No, it this case it had 3 elements and really looped the second file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a loop, decide what's next from the "ended" listener:

```
var current = 0;
// ...
player.addEventListener("ended",function() {
    current = current + 1 < array.length ? ++current : 0;
    this.src = "audio/" + array[current] + ".mp3";
    this.play();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Now it goes through all my files (e.g. 3) and loops then the first one.

Comment: yeah, current never gets reset to 0 when it loops around, but it should.

Comment: @andi True, fixed that. No more `next`.

Comment: Thank, it works now. But since it isn't in a for loop anymore, the whole playlist is being looped now. Is there any way to limit the repetitions?

Comment: @user1170330 I'm not sure what you mean/want, but couldn't you use a separate array for just the files you'd like to loop?

Comment: @user1170330 Make the function body look like this: `if(++current < array.length){ this.src = "audio/" + array[current] + ".mp3"; this.play(); }`. Of course use proper indentation: http://jsfiddle.net/LtEfS/

Comment: @Paulpro: In your case it only plays the first file.